# How do I group every each 'HELLO THERE WORLD' lines?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

[image]

I want to capture the 'HELLO THERE WORLD' lines, but use the start and the end lines. However, it's just taking the last line.

regex: `start\n(((\w+) (.+) (.+))\n)+end`

examples:

```
abcd 123 123
start
abcd 123 123
abcd 123 123
abcd 123 123
end
abcd 123 123
```

In the examples I want all the text between the start and the end to be In 3 groups for each line(`group1=abcd,group2=123,group3=123`)
like that:

[image]

Comment: Good that you have shared your efforts. Please do add samples in form of text in your question along with your tried regex so that we can test our solutions on text based samples, thank you.

Comment: Which language or regex flavor do you use?

Comment: I use python flavor

Comment: What should be the match if there is `start` on a newline right after `end`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?s)(?!.*?start)^(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)(?=.*?end)
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/fDcMJd/1

Comment: I've just realized... if you don't have "start" in your data, you might possibly get incorrect results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF1ZH.png

Comment: yes, I see 
now problem is that it's continuing to search until the end

Comment: look here https://ibb.co/7gcYK3b
Does it have a solution?

Comment: Take a look at [this smart answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73236799/how-do-i-group-every-each-hello-there-world-lines/73237934#73238675). It seems to cover the edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all capture groups between start and end, you can make use of the Python [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and the `\G` anchor to get consecutive matches.

```
(?:^start(?=(?:\n(?!start$|end$).*)*\nend$)|\G(?!^))\n(?!end\b)(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^start` Match `start` at the start of the string
  - `(?=(?:\n(?!start$|end$).*)*\nend$)` Assert that the word `end` is present without crossing the word `start`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\n` Match a newline
- `(?!end\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not the word `end` directly to the right
- `(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)` Capture group 1, 2 and 3 containing 1 or more word characters

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/onMNYU/1) and a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##pVJBC8IgGD3nrzDZwW@NQXULYqeIoDrVTQYr3RqUGypUsP@@nOtQtCgKEZ/v6XvIs7yaQyHHdZ2fykIZrEQmLgiViTFCSTzFitBoEmuTKEOjqcVM0qjv9l4lJPcg9MFn0sGKza0YA7hDlmI7oOw8AKYfF4KQttaUJLs9x8PRuJlMEtQjzriFr@I3TBPaITWj@8JDIhdp9ix@w7xN/Jj32wv/MwBbrsqloa7pMM0lT45Hei88wDpo/0C42i43i@ViPQOo6xs).

Comment: Great answer! Could you please shed the light on which part causes the pattern not work in python's re module? In other cases, I know one cause could be non-fixed length lookbehinds, but I see you haven't used them here.

Comment: @ZygD The `\G` anchor is not supported in `re`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

`/(?<=start\n.*)(?:^([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+)$)(?=.*\nend)/gms`

It should match every line with 3 words between start and end, and group those 3 words.

See [example](https://regexr.com/6r7v0)

Comment: Hi, Thank you :)
this regex is capturing all the words to only 3 groups
I want 3 groups in each line
In every line 3 groups

Comment: Wait, so you want the first group to be the first word of every line, the second group to be the second word of every line and the third group to be the third word of every line ?

Comment: no, I want 3 groups in every line
look at the screenshot In my question

Comment: every line is a match and there are 3 groups in every match(the three words)

Comment: See my example, it feels like the regex does what you want